# How to set properties based on an initial configuration?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I'd been searching for so long and I cannot find a concrete answer. Let's say I have an extended control from panel like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.admin.User',{
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
config: {
    canAdd: false,
    canDelete: false,
    canEdit: false
},
constructor: function(config){
    this.initConfig(config);
    this.callParent(arguments);
},
xtype: 'user',
requires: [
    'MyApp.view.admin.UsersGrid',
    'MyApp.view.admin.UserModel',
    'MyApp.view.admin.UserController',
    'MyApp.model.User'
],
viewModel: {
    type: 'user'
},
controller: 'user',
frame: true,
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'stretch'
},
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'users-grid',
        flex: 1
    }
],
dockedItems: [
    {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'top',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Add',
                glyph: MyApp.util.Glyphs.getGlyph('add'),
                hidden: **[config.canAdd]**
                listeners: {
                    click: 'onAdd'
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                bind: {
                    disabled: '{!usersGrid.selection}'
                },
                text: 'Edit',
                hidden: **[config.canEdit]**
                hidden: this.setElementConfiguration,
                glyph: Mofeg.util.Glyphs.getGlyph('edit'),
                listeners: {
                    click: 'onEdit'
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                bind: {
                    disabled: '{!usersGrid.selection}'
                },
                text: 'Eliminar',
                glyph: MyApp.util.Glyphs.getGlyph('destroy'),
                listeners: {
                    click: 'onDelete'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]});
```

I want to apply the hidden properties of the buttons based on the initial configurations, how can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an [`initComponent`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-initComponent):

```
initComponent: function () {
    var me = this,
        editButton = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[itemId=edit]')[0],
        canEdit = me.getCanEdit();

    editButton.setHidden(canEdit);

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```